# Why is it possible to add functions to external library to access internal data

Tags: c++, dll, static-libraries

this week i needed a feature in our internal static library but i was too lazy to recompile the library so i just modified the header file and was able to get access to private members. The same was possible to do when the library is a Windows dll.

An example header might look like:

```
#pragma once

#ifdef DLL
#define DLL_INTERFACE __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLL_INTERFACE
#endif

class DLL_INTERFACE foo
{
public:
    foo(); // init foo::a and foo::b to 0

    int getA() const;
    void setA(int a); // set foo::a to a and foo::b to a+2
private:
    int a;
    int b;
};
```

Now i added my own functions to the the header that allow me access to its private members like so:

```
class DLL_INTERFACE foo
{
public:
    foo(); // init foo::a and foo::b to 0

    int getA() const;
    void setA(int a); // set foo::a to a and foo::b to a+2

    int getB() const
    {
        return b;
    }
    void setB(int b)
    {
        this->b = b;
    }
private:
    int a;
    int b;
};
```

While testing my new functionality and recompiling the library (to not rely on that hack) i realized that this could compromise the internal state of the object.

Why is this allowed/possible to change the header files of a compiled library (dll or static lib)? (I had expected that the compiler or the linker would complain that the object from the library does not match the object defined in the header)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Because the design of C++ is intended to prevent you from accidents but not to prevent you from abuse...

Comment: I'd like to frame challenge this question: how would you prevent someone from modifying the header file? Since you generally need to distribute headers as source, you cannot prevent someone doing modifications. But then, it's obviously their fault if they break ABI compatibility (and it's relatively simple to do) and your library stops working. There's also licensing stuff to take into account (you may be explicitly forbidden from modifying), but again, you cannot force it, maybe only take license violation to the court.

Comment: Code in a header (i.e. inlined code) becomes part of the caller. So, no change to the libraries binary is necessary to corrupt its data. If it wouldn't be a change in the header, there still would be other ways to achieve this. With a `reinterprete_cast` you can achieve nearly everything (but most of that is probably U.B.)

Comment: I needed a bit to find the resp. quote: [C++ tries to guard against Murphy, not Machiavelli. - Damian Conway](https://www.quotemaster.org/qfcab36f08b08750a3aacc03c3e616b97) ;-)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen at least for a dll i would have expected that the compiled part of the library has a hash or another check for the 'exported class' that would then be checked against the used (and modified) interface throwing some sort of compile/link error.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat the problem i see is that with that information one should never publish a library that does not hide its internal members or else a user might change the internal state creating UB.

Comment: You might be interested in the [pimpl idiom](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl), which does quite a good job at hiding implementation details. Problem with having a hash is that the library had seen it's own header and cannot quite see the header included by other .cpp file. Inside library code, you could try to find the header that is used (not sure if this is really possible) and see if haven't been tampered with, but user can copy content of the header and modify that copy. You cannot prevent all UB that user wants to have, and you probably shouldn't try to.

Comment: There is a usual resort for your issue -> the [PImpl idiom](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl). Have a look at [woboq.org](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/). Qt uses it a lot to hide implementation details of their widgets. (Not that I like this...) ;-)

Comment: @Zaiborg "*at least for a dll i would have expected that the compiled part of the library has a hash or another check for the 'exported class' that would then be checked against the used (and modified) interface throwing some sort of compile/link error*" - nope, nothing like that exists in C/C++. Why would you have expected that?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I would have expected the `__declspec(dllexport)` to generate some sort of hash and when the class is imported from the dll the interface is checked if it is valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing a header in this manner and recompiling a part of the program with the changed header results in a violation of the ["One Definition Rule"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) and thus is undefined behaviour.

This kind of violation *could have been* detected by a C++ implementation. Such detection is not very challenging technically. Basically, the compiler computes hashes of all definitions that it sees, and stores the names-to-hashes dictionary in the object file, and the linker checks that they all match. The method is not too different from name-mangling that existing implementations employ. However, this entails changes in the linker, and possibly in the object file format, and also increases compilation and link times. Which is why the implementations are not eager to implement it, and consequently the C++ standard is unlikely to mandate it. So it will probably remain a no-diagnostic-required violation.

Comment: Shame that his is not the case. Thanks for the clarification.